# Dealing with transactions and arrays with Firebase database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving leaderboard data using [save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions)

I am looking for a way to remove the array numbering with Firebase transactions and replace them with `userId` for me to be able to update user information.
Code:

```
 private TransactionResult AddScoreTransaction(MutableData mutableData)
    {
        playerNewGlobalScore = false;
        List<object> leaders = mutableData.Value as List<object>;
        if (leaders == null)
        {
            leaders = new List<object>();
        }
        else if (mutableData.ChildrenCount >= LeaderBoardManager.Instance.MaxScoreRows)
        {
            // If the current list of scores is greater or equal to our maximum allowed number,
            // we see if the new score should be added and remove the lowest existing score.
            long minScore = long.MaxValue;
            object minVal = null;

            foreach (var child in leaders)
            {
                if (!(child is Dictionary<string, object>))
                    continue;
                long childScore = (long)((Dictionary<string, object>)child)["score"];
                if (childScore < minScore)
                {
                    minScore = childScore;
                    minVal = child;
                }
            }
            // If the new score is lower than the current minimum, we abort.
            if (minScore > Score)
            {
                return TransactionResult.Abort();
            }
            // Otherwise, we remove the current lowest to be replaced with the new score.

            leaders.Remove(minVal);
        }

        // Now we add the new score as a new entry that contains the email address and score.
        Dictionary<string, object> newScoreMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        newScoreMap["name"] = Name;
        newScoreMap["country"] = Country;
        newScoreMap["photoUrl"] = PhotoUrl;
        newScoreMap["level"] = Level;
        newScoreMap["userId"] = UserId;
        newScoreMap["score"] = Score;

        leaders.Add(newScoreMap);

        // You must set the Value to indicate data at that location has changed.
        mutableData.Value = leaders;

        playerNewGlobalScore = true;
        return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
    }
```

Real time database example:
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble making your code work. In that case, make sure your question includes the [minimum, complete, standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not sure what to code to show, i use the code exactly as the link provided, with a few more fields like userId, photoUrl and displayName. There is no clue in the documents of how to update Transactions that are stored like Arrays.

Comment: Why do tou store like arrays? The 0,1,2 indexes needs to be userId. İn this way, users will be easily altered by id

Comment: @Simonare That is true, i can also do that with by changing how to store leaderboard (redo everything), however, since using Transactions, the Array numbering are generated automatically. See Firebase examples: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions) And i did not find any way to remove it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Question updated.

Comment: Thanks. What's the problem when you run this code? Also: is there any way you can reduce the amount of code, and still have the same problem (as it's quite long right now)? Finally: how do you call `AddScoreTransaction` (specifically: on what `DatabaseReference` do you run the transaction?

Comment: There is no problem with code, besides that it generating the array 0,1 2, etc.. which makes it difficult to update values later since i do not have a child of userId. I call the code with   `DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Leaders").Child(Genre);
        reference.RunTransaction(AddScoreTransaction)`

Comment: I tried to reduce code, still same thing, i guess this is how Transactions works

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans
Firebase does not support C# and they are happy about that(see https://stackshare.io/stackups/firebase-vs-pusher-vs-signalr), firestore does.
They suggest you go to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

However https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet  from Step Up Labs, Inc. (use NuGet Firebase) is useful for the for all the things you want to do over the REST API https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database 
In the underbelly of the docs is "**Conditional requests**, the REST equivalent of SDK 
**Transaction Operations**, update data according to a certain condition. See an overview of the workflow and learn more about conditional requests for REST in Saving Data." and that can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-conditional-requests

 Hope that is of some help.